# Does the も particle in this sentence have the role as は?

Tags: particle-は, particle-も

> ハグリッドの声がくぐもっていた。
>   「淋しいといけないから、テディベアの縫いぐるみも入れてやった。」

Does the も particle in this sentence have the role as は, subject particle ? Then why is 入れて here still in active form ?

Comment: This sentence doesn't sound like it was stated in isolation. Can you give us the surrounding sentences for some context?

Comment: This is the preceded sentence: ハグリッドの声がくぐもっていた。

Comment: は is not a subject particle.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how to explain it in English.

Answer (score 1):

This も replaces を, the direct object marker.

> - テディベアの縫いぐるみを入れてやった。 I put in the Teddy Bear (for her/him).
> - テディベアの縫いぐるみ**も**入れてやった。 I put in the Teddy Bear (for her/him), **too**.

- も can safely replace を as well as は. I'm a bit surprised that some pages (like [this one](http://lingwiki.com/index.php?title=Japanese_particles#.E3.82.82_.28mo.29)) have failed to mention this fact.
- ～を入れる = put something in (maybe into a coffin, in this context?)
- やる here is a subsidiary verb that indicates the action taker does it for the sake of someone.

So no passive voice is concerned in this sentence.